# C# Console Application (Print to screen over time in console application in c sharp)

Tags: c#

I want to print over time without printing directly to the screen. For example, the program says "Hello" every 3 seconds.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.ReadLine();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want _”to print over time without printing directly to the screen.”_ … … then where do you want to print to?

Comment: @JohnG I believe he means he doesn't want it to immediately print to the screen. He wants there to be a delay.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to use the C# [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0). The example in the documentation is pretty solid and shows a 2 second interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.ReadLine();
```